# For every $A \in M(n,\mathbb R)$ , does there exist $B,C \in M(n,\mathbb R) \setminus \{kI:k \in \mathbb R\}$ such that $A=B+C$ and $BC=CB$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in M(n,\mathbb R)$ , then is it true that we can find $B,C \in M(n,\mathbb R)$ such that $B,C$ are not scalar multiple of $I$ , $BC=CB$ and $A=B+C$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that we need to assume that $n\geq 2$, since every $1\times 1$ matrix is a scalar multiple of the identity.

First, if $A$ is a scalar multiple of $I$, then it commutes with all matrices, so we can take $B$ to be any non-scalar multiple of $I$, and $C=A-B$.

Next, assume that $A$ is not a scalar multiple of $I$. Then neither are $B=2A$ and $C=-A$, and those two matrices satisfy the conditions in the statement.

Comment: To make the first answer more concrete: you can take $B$ to be all zeros, except that $b_{11} = a_{11}$, and $C = A$ except that $c_{11} = 0$. But neither this nor the answer given handles the case where $A = 0$ (at least not without a little interpretation:) ).. For that: let $B$ be all zero except $b_{11} = 1$, and let $C = -B$.